# Is Ubuntu good for Java development?

Tags: server, java, jdk, javascript, maven-3

I am going to develop an eCommerce site using Spring, JDK, Maven, jQuery, JavaScript, servlets, JSP and HTML.

Is Ubuntu good for developing a project like this? If I face any issue related to this topic, where can I ask about it?

Comment: I find it slightly amusing since your title asks for java, but the languages you listed (jquery, JavaScript) are not related to Java. But to answer your question - yes, you can develop java on Ubuntu and all the other stufd

Comment: It's ironic that the same article I posted in Stack Overflow Documentation is being reviewed as primarily opinion based when I posted an excerpt of it here.

Comment: @karel only questions can be reviewed as opinion based, not answers.

Comment: This is a huge project, and you've listed an impressive amount of technologies. Are you familiar with them ? If not, I doubt whether the project is feasible at all. If this is a "learn as I'm going along" type of project, I would advise not to add yet another unknown system to the list (Ubuntu). If you're experienced with windows, you can stick to it. That being said: Developing on Ubuntu is in many cases much easier than on windows. If you already have experience with eCommerce development, the switch to Ubuntu would probably be a good idea.

Comment: Another tip: A good IDE is much more important than the operating system. I'm using PyCharm, Clion, QtCreator and Matlab on both windows and ubuntu and rarely need OS specific configuration (yes even C++ works beautifully on windows, thanks to a sophisticated CMake setup).

Comment: And a third tip (maybe most important): This is not a one-man job,  you should have a team.  Of course you could do this alone, but that would take very much time and very much dedication. Ask the team what it prefers. Do all of you use windows as default system ? Are all of you willing to make the switch ? Ubuntu can be a horrible time-sink, if people don't know what they are doing. Expect that for the first week or so, there will be one person with a broken development-environment.

Answer (score 5):

The first part of this answer was copied from the [Ubuntu for Developers](https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/developers) page.

> ***Why use Ubuntu for development?***
>
> - The fastest route from development to deployment on desktop, mobile, server or cloud
> - The desktop of choice for developers at some of the world's leading technology companies
> - The broadest and best development tools and libraries
> - Lightweight to either run natively or in a VM, on a PC or a Mac
> - Ideal for any resource-intensive environment
>
> ***Ubuntu is the world's most popular open source OS for development***
>
> Ubuntu is used by thousands of development teams around the world
>   because of its versatility, reliability, constantly updated features,
>   and extensive developer libraries.
>
> If you're managing developers, Ubuntu is the best way to increase your
>   team's productivity and guarantee a smooth transition from development
>   all the way to production. Ubuntu is the world’s most popular open
>   source OS for both development and deployment, from the data center to
>   the cloud.
>
> And, as the Ubuntu OS converges, these same applications will be able
>   to run on desktop, tablets, phone and even on the Internet of Things —
>   one application across Ubuntu's full range of devices.

---

> If I face any issue related to this topic, where can I ask about it?

The best source that I know of for introductory information about Spring, JDK, Maven, jQuery, JavaScript, servlets, JSP and HTML is the [Stack Overflow Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) pages. Stack Overflow Documentation has an overview of each one of these topics followed by useful code examples.